# Using the IN operator to filter in reporting services

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Can anyone advise what the syntax should be when using the IN operator within a table filter.
I have tried the below but the snytax is wrong:

[image]

Comment: This works without the equal sign.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you just change the **Value** property and just add a comma separated list of values that should work:

[image]

This worked for me in a quick test, anyway.

Books Online seems to be pretty light on examples, but I did find one reference; see the `In` example in [Commmonly Used Filters](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337292.aspx). It would be nice if this was explained better.

Comment: If this does not work I also recommend placing your values in quotations eg "criteria one","criteria two"

Comment: This doesn't work for me in Visual Studio 2017.  The designer keeps wanting to add "" (double double quotes) before and after each value.  Given the example above, it displays as """criteria one""", """criteria two""" after going back in and editing.

Answer (score 52):

I had some troubles with this one as well.  Microsofts [own documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc627464.aspx) states a simple comma delimited list of values in the Value box should work.  This is confusing because IT DOESN'T.  At least it didn't for me and I am using SSRS 2012 with Visual Studio 2010.

It turns out that when you are using the IN operator, SSRS is expecting an array of values.  There are a number of ways you can make this work for the filter.  The following examples are meant to be typed out in the expression editor.

The first way (also the way explained in the blog linked below) is to simply type your comma delimited list in a string value and then use the split function on it.

```
=split("2B,2C",",")
```

Or you can derive your list from a multi-value parameter.  The multi-value parameter is already an array so all you have to do is reference it via the parameter expression as seen below.

```
=Parameters!MultiValueParam.Value
```

I found out this information via the following blog. http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/simons/archive/2007/11/20/RS-Howto--Use-the-IN-operator-in-a-filter-expression.aspx

Comment: Split function works for VS 2013 & SSRS 2012. Poor documentation on Microsoft's part. It just simply does not work as advertised. Thanks to @Jordan H & the o.b.p.

Comment: very nice solution - this is so "shody" from MS

Answer (score 23):

This actually works:

```
=CStr("Value1,Value2,Value3,Value4,etc").Split(",")
```

This is tested in SSRS 2012.

Comment: This was the only solution that worked for me because the editor always surround the full expression with `""` if the expression does't start with `=`.
I was using Report Builder 3.0.

Comment: This is the only solution that **always** has worked for me. With the other ones, SSRS changes the value of the literals, but since this is a formula it doesn't alter it.

Answer (score 8):

```
"value1" "value2"
```

with one space and no comma worked for me. The funny thing is, when going back to look after testing, it appears as

```
value1, value2
```

with  a comma and no quotes.  If I cut that, then paste it directly back to the same field, it doesn't work. This is some buggy s**t right here.

Underlying datatype is nvarchar(10), not null

Tested with VS 2017 and SSRS 2016

Comment: That's exactly what I'm seeing too. Although I am using it in an .rdlc file in VS 2015.

Answer (score 4):

Remove the leading `=` from the expression, i.e.

```
"criteria one" , "criteria two"
```

Answer (score 4):

If the recommended solution somehow doesn't work for you, try using a semicon as a seperator.

Example: criteria one; criteria two

It worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

For integer values you can use:

Type: Text

Operator: In

Value: =New Integer() {8800,8820}

Should work on 2008 R2 and newer versions

Answer (score 3):

I know this works:

1. My SP returns VARCHAR(n) for the field I will filter in the tablix. Returning INT **does not work** in my solution. I don't know why (yet).
2. report.param.allow multiple values = true
3. tablix.filter.expression.datatype = text
4. tablix.filter.operator = IN
5. tablix.filter.value = =SPLIT(JOIN(Parameters!id.Value,","),",")

Using this method, I was able to call the SP once, use it in a param to get available values, run the report, and the tablix table read the selected data from step #5 above and displayed the correct number of rows.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me in SSRS 2012.

"criteria one", "criteria two"

Answer (score 1):

My problem was finally solved after many attempts, only using this method.

**Expression:**

=InStrRev(*complete string with delimiter*,*value to search*)

**Type:** Integer

**Operator:** <>

**Value:** 0

Comment: Thanks, this is the ONLY way it worked for me as well. (I am using Power BI Report Builder)

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio 2013 Premium, the IN operator worked fine with a multivalued parameter:

```
=Parameters!MultiValueParam.Value
```

However, when I wanted to use constant values in my set, I could not get the IN operator to work entering text or an expression via the UI.

What finally worked with a set of constant values was entering the Code view and editing my Filter manually. The XML needed for a set of constant strings "E", "G", and "H" is this:

```
<Filters>                                                                                            
  <Filter>                                                                                              
    <FilterExpression>=Fields!det.Value</FilterExpression>                                                                                              
    <Operator>In</Operator>                                                                                              
    <FilterValues>                                                                                                
      <FilterValue>E</FilterValue>                                                                                                
      <FilterValue>G</FilterValue>
      <FilterValue>H</FilterValue>                                                                                              
    </FilterValues>                                                                                            
  </Filter>                                                                                          
</Filters>
```

Comment: This worked for me.  I had one filter value that was an expression (parameter value) and two more filter values that were each constants.  Because my parameter was an integer type, I needed to make my constant filter values expressions i.e. <FilterValue>=1</FilterValue>

Answer (score 1):

For integer values this worked for me:

- Expression:  MyNumber
- Operator:   In
- Value:      10; 12; 124

See image link:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Enter this query into expression:

```
=Join(Parameters!MultiValueParam.Value)
```

Answer (score 0):

My values included forward slashes. The only way I could get SSRS's <kbd>In      ▼</kbd> operator to handle them correctly was with the expression `=``CStr("google / cpc,bing / cpc").Split(",")`

Answer (score 0):

Probably I'm with a more recent versión of SSRS. Values type are **text**. For me worked as,

```
"criteria 1";"criteria 2";...;"criteria N"
```

Doble quotes are mandatory.

Answer (score 0):

Universal solution:

Expression: [*columnName*]

Operator:  In

Value:     [@*parameterName*]

Answer (score -3):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rn5Uu.jpg)

Each every between numeric value  need one space. its working fine